# Simple sitemap using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying achieve simple site for the group of list elements(list within list)

I am facing two issues :

Displaying in tree structure

example on clicking -xxyy1 , displaying child elements inline as tree below xxyy1 and so on for child elements as shown in screenshot[image]

Second is creating breadcrumb for each click on parent and child elements

codepen URL for reference:http://codepen.io/divyar34/pen/YZNmyK

```
HTML:

<body>
  <div id="breadcrumbs"></div>
<div>

  <h1>Home Page</h1>



        <header>
            <div>
                <nav>
                     <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a>xyz</a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>aa</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>bb</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>cc</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>a11
                                            <span>This link will open a new window</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>zzz</a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>One zzz</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>Two zzz</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>Three</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>Four</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>About ab12</a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>iii</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>jjj</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>b11</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a>c11</a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>c12</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>c13</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>c14</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>d11</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a>dd1</a>
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>dd2</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a>dd3
                        <span>This link will open a new window</span></a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </nav>
            </div>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <nav>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a>ab12<span>ab12 Home Page</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a>xxyy</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a>xxyy1</a>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>abc1<h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>1111</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>1112</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>1113</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>1114</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>1115</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </h3></div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>abc2</h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>2221</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>2222</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>2223</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>2224</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>2225</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>abc3</h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>3331</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>3332</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>3333</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>3334</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>abc4</h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>4441</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>4442</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>4443</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>4444</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>4445</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a>zzz1</a>
                                            <div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>kk1</h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>kk11</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>kk22</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>kk33</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <h3>kk2</h3>
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a>kk21</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>kk22</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>kk23</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li><a>kk24</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                        </li>







                                    </ul>
                                </li>


                                <li>

                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
</div>      

<div></div>


</body>

CSS:

a{
    border:1px solid black;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 5px;
}
ul li{

list-style-type:none;
display:inline; 
cursor:pointer;
}



nav{
display:inline;
}


div, ul{
display:inline; 
}

ul li ul{
display:none;
padding:5px;
}

h1{
  text-align:center;
}

.siteBlock{
  display:inline; 
}

.child{
  color:red;
}


JS:
$('li ul').addClass('child');

$('ul:not(.child) li').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).first('a').text())
  var curr = $(this).first('a').text();
 $('#breadcrumbs').append(curr);  $(this).find('.child').css('display','inline')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled going through your entire tree of elements, however why don't you do something like the following:

Create a variable that contains an array of all of your pages:

```
var pages = ["Home", "About", "Contact"];
```

Then, run a loop on those, calling a function that builds an `HTML` element for the tree:

```
$.each(pages, function(i, e) {

      var html = BuildTemplate(e, i > 0);
      $("body").append(html);

});
```

The function is the following:

```
function BuildTemplate(pageTitle, appendCarrot) {

  result = "";

  if (appendCarrot) {
    result += " -> ";
  }

  result += "<a href='http://www.yahoo.com' target='_blank'>";
  result += pageTitle;
  result += "</a>";
  return result;
}
```

**Working Demo: http://jsbin.com/lovategiva/edit?js,console,output**

Now, you'll probably want to store a URL with the name of the page and pass that through to the `BuildTemplate` method and pass that through to the `href` to link it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks James, but the example yu used works for breadcrumb of limited pages and it doesn't slow the sitemap kind display

Comment: @divyareddy You can still style them the way you have them now to look nice. Also, it's not for limited pages. I'm not sure where you're getting your data for your pages, but as long as you add all of your pages to that array, you'll be set.